# cannot find module 'oracledb'

Tags: node.js, oracle

`npm start` yielding

```
Error: Cannot find module 'oracledb'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

I know it's something about PATH. I have multiple Oracle-related values set in PATH in the order it appears:

1) `C:\oracle64\product\12.1.0.2\client_1\bin` instantclient folder is at client_1 level, not in bin.

2) `c:\oracle\ODP_home1;` instantclient folder is at oracle folder, named `instantclient_12_1`.

3) `c:\oracle\instantclient_12_1`, seems answering No. 2

4) `C:\Oracle\oledb\bin`

Windows 7 64-bit, npm 6.1.0.

`npm install oracledb` getting

```
oracledb ERR! NJS-054: Binary build/Release/oracledb.node was not installed.
oracledb ERR! Pre-built binary packages are not available for this version of Node.js (NODE_MODULE_VERSION="59")
oracledb ERR! Failed to install binary package oracledb-v2.3.0-node-v59-win32-x64.gz
```

Comment: It’s complaining about your Node version in the second line of the Error Text block. Try upgrading to the newest LTS release or refer to the package docs for supported versions of Node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two links help solving the problem

1. Oracle's own [node installation](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#troubleshooting) troubling shooting.
2. force an [unsafe installation](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/832), eventually version 2.2 was installed instead of the supposed 2.3, and it's now running ok.

Comment: Following the first url, had to download and add the basic client to path. This solved the issue. Thanks @Jeb50

Answer (score 0):

### Upgrade your node version: v8.9.3

D:\stack>npm install oracledb

> oracledb@2.3.0 install D:\stack\node_modules\oracledb
>   node package/oracledbinstall.js

oracledb Beginning installation
oracledb Verifying installation
oracledb Continuing installation
oracledb Oracledb downloaded
oracledb Verifying installation
oracledb Binary SHA matches SHA in SHASUMS256.txt
oracledb
oracledb 
oracledb ** Node-oracledb 2.3.0 installation complete for Node.js 8.9.3 (win32,
x64)
oracledb **
oracledb ** To use the installed node-oracledb:
oracledb ** - You must have 64-bit Oracle client libraries in your PATH environm
ent variable
oracledb ** - If you do not already have libraries, install the Instant Client B
asic or Basic Light package from
oracledb **   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html
oracledb ** - A Microsoft Visual Studio Redistributable suitable for your Oracle
 client library version must be available
oracledb **   Check https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html for deta
ils
oracledb **
oracledb ** Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://oracle.github.io/no
de-oracledb/INSTALL.html
oracledb 
+ oracledb@2.3.0
added 1 package in 22.026s

*I have successfully npm install oracledb.*